# Efficiency of getOrElse vs match

Tags: scala

I've been told that the following pattern is more efficient than the simple match paradigm. I'm unsure if this is true, and I can't find any sources to corroborate.

Is using

```
values.headOption.map { x }.getOrElse(y)
```

more efficient than

```
values.headOption match { /* case statements */ }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-rigorous, non-scientific, meaningless micro-benchmark:

```
def measureTime[U](repeats: Long)(block: => U): Double = {
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis

  var iteration = 0
  while (iteration < repeats) {
    iteration += 1
    block
  }

  val end = System.currentTimeMillis
  (end - start).toDouble / repeats
}

val n: Long = 2000000000L
val emptyTime = measureTime(n) {
  /* do nothing */
}

val mapTime = {
  val list = List(1, 2)
  var sum = 0L

  val mapTime = measureTime(n) {
    sum += list.headOption.map(x => x * 42).getOrElse(0)
  }

  assert(sum == 42 * n)

  mapTime
}

val matchTime = {
  val list = List(1, 2)
  var sum = 0L

  val t = measureTime(n) {
    sum += (list.headOption match {
      case Some(x) => x * 42
      case None => 0
    })
  }

  assert(sum == 42 * n)

  t
}

println("empty:          " + emptyTime)
println("Map  :          " + mapTime)
println("match:          " + matchTime)
println("map-empty:      " + (mapTime - emptyTime))
println("match-empty:    " + (matchTime - emptyTime))
println("(map / match):  " + (mapTime / matchTime))
println("((mp - e) / (mt - e)): " + ((mapTime - emptyTime) / (matchTime - emptyTime)))
```

Output:

```
empty:                 1.2675E-6
Map  :                 1.10745E-5
match:                 1.65855E-5
map-empty:             9.807000000000001E-6
match-empty:           1.5317999999999998E-5
(map / match):         0.6677218051912817
((mp - e) / (mt - e)): 0.6402271837054447
```

The `map + getOrElse` version seemed to be 35% faster (or: the garbage collector kicked in at the wrong moment, and messed up measurements for the contrahent).

---

There is no reason why `getOrElse` shouldn't be faster, maybe it can spare some cycles here and there because it doesn't need to call `Some.unapply` and `None.unapply` and then construct additional `Option`s to signal whether a match succeeded. But: I don't see any significant order-of-magnitude-difference. Use what looks more readable. Your software project will most likely not fail because of a 30% slower O(1) operation, you can use your time and energy better if you optimize those parts of the code that actually matter.

Comment: You can use [ScalaMeter](https://scalameter.github.io/) to provide accurate benchmarks, in terms of CPU time and memory. It will remove the effects of garbage collection, JIT compilation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically the best version is

```
values.headOption.fold(y)(x)
```

because it only tests the state of the option once and does not create an intermediate Some() value (though this may well be optimised out by the compiler).

Using fold also adds some type checking which is not there with getOrElse, though this is sometimes a curse rather than a blessing!

Comment: Why is type checking "not there with getOrElse"?

Comment: @inline final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B

Comment: @inline final def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B): B

Comment: With `fold` the result type of `f` must match the type of `ifEmpty`, which is not the case for `getOrElse`.